# Is there a way to know the previous value of a `local` variable in signal handler?

Tags: perl

How do I recover STDOUT in a signal handler during the code block execution?

Is there a way to know the previous value of a `local` variable in signal handler?

Comment: asker: please don't completely change your question when you have a followup question; it makes nonsense of the existing answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a different filehandle dup'd from STDOUT before the local and use that in the signal handler.

Comment: So there's no way to do it out of the box,say,without duplicating `STDOUT`?

Comment: It *could* be done, but probably shouldn't be.  I have the feeling you really shouldn't be changing STDOUT in the first place...that you would be much better off just outputting to a different filehandle in your block.  But you'd have to talk about why you wanted to change STDOUT and show some of your code to get a clear answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    open my $devnull, '>', '/dev/null';
    local *STDOUT = $devnull;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without a local variable ?

Comment: Not reliably. You can `select` the new filehandle and `select STDOUT` back when you're done, but that only works if you can guarantee you'll hit the exit case (which won't happen properly on `die`). A `local` will always be reset when the block is exited, no matter how you exit.

Comment: If by "without a local variable" you mean "without `$devnull`", `open((local *STDOUT), '>', '/dev/null');`

Comment: How do I recover STDOUT in a signal handler during the code block execution?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) to save the old filehandle, like so:

```
{
    open my $fh, '>', '/dev/null';
    my $oldstdout = select($fh);
    print $oldstdout "This prints to STDOUT";
    print "Junk to /dev/null"
    select $oldstdout;
    print "Back to STDOUT";
}
```